# TensorFlow: How to convert image to 1 dimensional tensor?

Tags: tensorflow, png, mnist

I've recently used the mnist data set to build a model for predicting hand-written integers. I now want to use my own images. My images are 28x28 pixels (like the mnist set), but when I try to convert them into a tensor using tf.image.decode_png, I get a a 3D tensor [28, 28, 4]. From reading around, I believe the extra 4 is RGB related. How can I convert to [28, 28] ignoring any colour scale (if that is the actual problem, maybe I'm missing something entirely).

Thank you!

Comment: Hi TWilliamson, welcome to SO ! Can you share your a minimal reproducible example ?

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly said, you got a 3D tensor because your image have 3 RGB channels. You can use something like [tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/rgb_to_grayscale) to get what you want.